# Permutations of times that an element appear in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have a list:

```
lis={{a,b},{b,b},{a,a}}
```

This could be a list of types of something, 3 types: the type {a,b}, the type {b,b} and the type {a,a}.Then, I have ten individuals that could be of wherever of this three types. How many permutations could I have of the distribution of this 3 types in ten individuals.

```
AllPossibleStates= {{8,1,1},{7,2,1},{5,3,2}...{...}}
```

That means:
    {8,1,1}: 8 individuals of type {a,b}, 1 of type {b,b}, and 1 {a,a}
 and so on

I can make some with `IntegerPartitions`  but this doesn´t take into account some permutations like:

```
 {{10,0,0},{0,10,0},{0,0,10}}
```

Comment: *VERY* unclear question.  "Distribution" has a very specific meaning, which does not apply here.  Do you mean "permutations" or "combinations" or... *what*?

Comment: If you have problems describing what you want, please give an example where `StrategiesCopMap` is the input and `AllStatesPossible` is the expected output.

Comment: Try `Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[10, {3}, Range[0, 10]], 1]`.